# Testing return value of a custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

I am trying to write a test suit for this custom hook.

```js
export const useInitialMount = () => {
  const isFirstRender = useRef(true);

  // in the very first render the ref is true, but we immediately change it to false.
  // so the every renders after will be false.
  if (isFirstRender.current) {
    isFirstRender.current = false;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

Very simple returns `true` or `false`.
As I saw, I should use `@testing-library/react-hooks`
and here is my try:

```js
test("should return true in the very first render and false in the next renders", () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => {
    useInitialMount();
  });
  expect(result.current).toBe(true);
});
```

but I got `undefined` which doesn't make sense it should be either `true` or `false`.

PS: the code works as expected on the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for the `renderHook` call is not quite right in your test.

Note the curly brackets, you should return `useInitialMount()` from `renderHook` callback, not just call it inside it (hence why you get `undefined`).

```js
test('should return true in the very first render and false in the next renders', () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useInitialMount());
  expect(result.current).toBe(true);
});
```

**Edit:** To clarify, the difference here is that:

Calling `() => { useInitialMount(); });` returns `undefined`, there are no return statements so the function will return `undefined` by default.

But calling `() => useInitialMount()` (which is short syntax for `() => { return useInitialMount(); }`) will return the value of calling the hook.

Reference: [Arrow Functions > Functions body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body).

Comment: the syntax is exactly what the doc says https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library. the result has value but the current value is undefiend.

Comment: @morteza I've added an edit clarifying my answer. Let me know if that makes sense now.

Comment: thanks a lot it works I missed the pointt