# result.current is null when using renderHook () Custom Hook to test custom hook in react-native using jest and testing-library

Tags: react-native, ts-jest, react-hooks-testing-library

For My project I am using one custom hook for navigation some of my screens as from one screen to another screen based on the parameters provide to the function of custom hook. How could I Unit Test it for React Native Custom

```js
const {result} = renderHook(() => {useShoppingCartNavigator()});
```

The problem is I am getting `result.current` as void and unable to call function of the hook

But according to the doc it should be like

```js
result.current.customHookFn();
```

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Testing return value of a custom hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66176284/1870780)?

Comment: Yes This helped me out for this error, Although now I am getting some other error..

TypeError: (0 , _stack.createStackNavigator) is not a function

    const ProductStack = createStackNavigator();

When I am trying to test my navigator,If I will mock this then will get another other due to mocking the function which I have to test
...


Thanks a lot for your help...

Answer (score 1):

The callback inside your renderHook is not returning anything because you wrapped your customHook on curlybraces. It should be

```
const {result} = renderHook(() => useShoppingCartNavigator());
```

Comment: What effect did adding the curly braces there have?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson omitting the curly braces causes an implicit return of the expression after the arrow.  Using curly braces tells the function to expect an explicit `return` statement, otherwise it returns `undefined`.

Comment: RenderHook API reference: https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library/blob/3f944e36b9811ecb5d4518492b928946cde0947d/docs/api-reference.md